# Is there any tool to highlight / color Quotes in Outlook (prefered) or Thunderbird?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-client

Is there a tool that can highlight / color Quotelevels (marked by > per level) in Outlook (prefered) or Thunderbird?

Opensource is preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this thunderbird addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/170/

> Quote Colors allows you to select text
>   and background colors of different
>   quote levels which are applied when
>   reading or printing mail/news
>   messages. Additionally, you can choose
>   between graphical and traditional
>   plain text quoting display mode.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea is something similar exists for Outlook???

Comment: I don't use outlook, so I don't know.  Keep bumping this question, though, to see if you can get an answer.